# After the client is disconnected, how does the server know when it reconnects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I currently have a chat.

If the client connection is unstable and the socket connection is lost, the server will recognize it as socket.disconnect and delete the client from the chat room.

Then, when reconnecting, the client automatically exits the room.

How do I resolve this?

The idea is to create a setTimeout at disconnect to hold the client for 20 seconds to be deleted from the chat room, and then delete the setTimeout when reconnecting.

When doing this, how do you know that the client is reconnected?

Does socket.id change when reconnected?

If socket.id does not change because I created a user-specific array based on socket.id, I think we can solve this problem at the moment.

```
socket.on('reconnect', function() {
   if( typeof event_timeout[socket.id] !== "undefined" )
     clearTimeout(event_timeout[socket.id]);
}
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
   event_timeout[socket.id] = setTimeout( exit_chat, 20000 ); 
}
```

Comment: Oh right! I will fix it. Thank you.

Comment: `socket.id` does change when a client reconnects

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So how does the server know that this socket is a reconnect socket? Do I have to check using user id instead of socket.id?

Comment: I try to connect/disconnect/reconnect but I don't know how to reconnect "manually"

Comment: I do not want to reconnect manually. I just wonder how the server should detect and respond when it reconnects (automatically).

Comment: I want to simulate reconnecting manually to check the server's behaviour - but reconnecting never happens, I can connect/disconnect/connect, I have never seen a reconnect

Comment: Ah! In my case, I temporarily shut down and restart the notebook's wireless network. In fact, this may be a simple connect after a disconnect, but I have experimented with this method because I need to be prepared in case the network situation is bad.

Comment: It seems there is no such system event as `reconnect`

Comment: Then I can not distinguish between reconnected and just connected. Thank you. If I did not know that, I almost wasted my time on it.